# Getting the count of GitHub repositories for a search query

Tags: github, github-api

I want to get the total count of GitHub repositories having oauth implementations in Spring framework.
I can use this query
`https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=oauth+spring+language:java&order=asc&per_page=100` which returns the GitHub repositories I am looking for with 100 repositories per page.

But GitHub API can return a maximum of 1000 repositories. Hence when I go to the 11-th page with the query `https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=oauth+spring+language:java&order=asc&per_page=100&page=11` GitHub API returns the following

`{
    "message": "Only the first 1000 search results are available",
    "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3/search/"
}`

Can anyone give any search query which would give me the count of GitHub repositories having oauth implementations in Spring framework?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `total_count` field on the first response will show the total count of repositories matching. For your example, I see `3530` results:

```
{
  "total_count": 3530,
  "incomplete_results": false,
  "items": [
    // items in here
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I  totally overlooked this `total_count` field in the JSON response. :-)